# If $A,B$ are any $3 \times 3$ matrices, then $A+B=B+A$ and $AB=BA$

Tags: logic

This question seems to be easy but not obvious, it consists of little bit of confusion.

What should be the $\text{negation of the following statement}$:

> If $A,B$ are any $3 \times 3$ matrices, then $A+B=B+A$ and $AB=BA$.

The statement is not true. But how to negate it ?

If I say:

> If $A,B$ are any $3 \times 3$ matrices, then $A+B=B+A$ and $AB \neq BA$.

This is a negation but not clear.

Any help

Comment: Shouldn't it be "there exist 3 x 3 matrices A, B such that $A+B\ne B+A$ or $AB=BA$"?

Comment: "For all" becomes "there exists"; "and" becomes "or".

Comment: @Divide1918 That should be "... or $AB \neq BA$"

Comment: Negation of the universal quantifier is the existential  quantifier. Also the negation of $r\land s$ is $\lnot r\lor\lnot s.$ Now carefully combine these to obtain the negation of your statement.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, indeed. I misread the original statement.

Comment: To be fair, the original statement is worded in a way that makes it less than obvious it's a universal statement. Unfortunately this is common in mathematics: an if-then statement is often implicitly a universal statement.

Comment: So would a "proper" negation be like "$A$ and $B$ are any $3\times3$ matrices, and either $A+B\ne B+A$ or $AB\ne BA$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More formally, we would say that original statement as

$$(\forall A,B \in M_{3 \times 3}(F))(A+B = B+A \; \land \; AB = BA)$$

For simplicity, define the predicate such that $P$ corresponds to $A+B=B+A$ and $Q$ so that $AB=BA$:

$$(\forall A,B \in M_{3 \times 3}(F))(P \land Q)$$

To negate a statement, you change all quantifiers around, and negate the predicate:

$$(\exists A,B \in M_{3 \times 3}(F))\Big( \neg (P \land Q) \Big)$$

Of course, the question remains, what is $\neg (P\land Q)$? If you'll remember, it is $\neg P \lor \neg Q$. Thus, the negation is

$$(\exists A,B \in M_{3 \times 3}(F))(\neg P \lor \neg Q)$$

i.e.

$$(\exists A,B \in M_{3 \times 3}(F))(A+B \ne B+A \; \lor \; AB \ne BA)$$

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to negate it is:

> There exists $A,B$ which are $3 \times 3$ matrices, such that $A+B\neq B+A$ **or** $AB\neq BA$.

Draw a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) may help when meeting logics.